# how to insert into multiple table using eloquent or DB facade in laravel from a single form

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have created a form using bootstrap and I have three tables in the database. The table names are

- product
- payment
- cheque.

Now I want to insert data into these three tables from my single form using eloquent or DB facade.

#### Form code:

Here is controller method.

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $product=new Product;
    $product->product_name=$request->input('product_name');
    $product->product_code=$request->input('product_code');
    $product->product_price=$request->input('product_price');
    $product->product_unit=$request->input('product_unit');
    $product->total=$request->input('t_amt');
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply,

```
    public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $product=new Product;
        .
        .
        .
        $product->save();

        $payment=new Payment;
        .
        .
        .
        $payment->save();

        $cheque=new Cheque;
        .
        .
        .
        $cheque->save();

    }
```